# C# starting up NetSH commandline

Tags: c#, cmd, process, netsh

For my school project I want to setup a connection via NetSH using C#.
I have googled somethings up and came up with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Server_Smart_Road
{
    class Connection
    {
        private string FileName { get; }
        private string Command { get; set; }
        private bool UseShellExecute { get; }
        private bool RedirectStandardOutput { get; }

        private bool CreateNoWindow { get; }

        public Connection()
        {
            FileName = "netsh.exe";
            Command = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=SmartRoad key=smartroad123";
            UseShellExecute = false;
            RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            CreateNoWindow = true;

        }

        public void ChangeCommand(string command)
        {
            Command = command;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = Command;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = UseShellExecute;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = RedirectStandardOutput;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = CreateNoWindow;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I run first an instance called ' process ' (run ()) to configure the connection, and then I use the same method and so a new instance with the same name for a command for startup.

In the form I am making a new instance of this class (Connection) with this code:

```
       private void btn_startnetwork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new Connection();
        connection.Run();
        connection.ChangeCommand("wlan start hostednetwork");
        connection.Run();
    }
```

The problem is: I don't see any program opening when 
I click on the button. I know that I have said that 'CreateNoWindow' should be true, but even when I set it on false, it won't start up netSH. As a result, I do not know whether the program does what it should do.

And I am starting a new process just for another command. This process starts netsh.exe again. I don't know if this is correct or not.

Comment: your process will never start. after the line with CreateNoWindow add process.Start(); see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: o damn im dumb... Thank you @ralf.w. Should I dispose it after each command or not?

Comment: at the end of Run() your process is history ;-) (disposed by .net garbage collector)

Comment: @ralf.w doesn't garbage collector take more time to dispose it?

Comment: more time as starting netsh.exe ?? or waiting for the next mouse click ?

Comment: I mean if you compare process.Dispose() to Garbage collector Dispose. Which one is the fastest? @ralf.w.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155308/discussion-between-ralf-w-and-gigitex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you should rewrite Run():

```
public void Run(string cmd)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = UseShellExecute;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = RedirectStandardOutput;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = CreateNoWindow;
        process.Start();
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
connection = new Connection();
connection.Run("wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=SmartRoad key=smartroad123");
```

or even shorter (your second call):

```
new Connection().Run("wlan start hostednetwork");
```

with an additional contructor

```
public Connection(string fn) : this()
{
    FileName = fn;
}
```

this looks even nicer:

```
new Connection("netsh.exe").Run("wlan set hostednetwork ... ");
new Connection("netsh.exe").Run("wlan start hostednetwork");
```

Comment: If use the additional constructor. What happens with my properties? How does it know  the information?

Comment: the part * : this()* calls the default constructor first. If you want to change your properties, you have to put your Connection to a variable first (Connection first = new Connection();  first.xxx = zzz; first.Run(); etc.)

Comment: So for the last part u are saying that I need to make a new instance for each proces?

Comment: you have been creating new process-instances all the time. var c = new Connection(); ... will create new Connection-instances.